# Clipboard trims whitespace on last line in Debian Stretch (GNOME)

Tags: debian, gnome, clipboard

I've noticed that when I copy and paste something, the last line, which may have been indented, is no longer indented when I paste.

For example, this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0011_update_proxy_permissions'),
    ]

    operations = [
        …
    ]
```

becomes this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0011_update_proxy_permissions'),
    ]

    operations = [
        …
]
```

Is there any way for me to correct this issue?

Comment: Hmmm.... tried any of these https://www.tecmint.com/best-clipboard-managers-for-linux/ Clipboard alternatives, just for troubleshooting purposes?

Comment: The issue strangely disappeared. I'll try out your suggestion if it comes back.